# Unable to install 18.04 on new hardware

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, system-installation

I'm running a 970 Evo on a relatively new motherboard (z370P D3)

Although it shouldn't cause any issues I'm now officially suspecting something is up.

I've created an installer using Rufus and the official latest iso (18.04.01)

Upon booting, I'm using previously dedicated 20G of free space which I then format as ext4, mount at `/` and continue.

Depending on whether or not I've attempted this before a full format a few things happen:

1. Progress is stuck permanently "failed to fetch resource ID 7071"
2. Crash

I've tried every possible permutation of install type (minimal, not minimal, download, not download, from USB or from a temporarily booted system) but no dice.

The only thing that stands out to me is that the installer complains a lot about a pci-e error which it calls "corrected" - since the 970 EVO is a PCIe drive, I suspect it may be the culprit.

That being said I'm about as lost as I am frustrated so any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: During boot, try give kernel options acpi=linux

Comment: @DomoNCar Since I'm running it off a rufus iso, I don't think I'm able to set that option. Am I incorrect?

Comment: You are incorrect. Follow the instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD_Boot_Option_Configuration_Line to check the various boot options. Also try other acpi options there.